# Can I redirect customer back to my store from Stripe Hosted Invoice page?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm generating `Invoice` object in Stripe and then redirecting customer to the `hosted_invoice_url` (https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-hosted_invoice_url)

After customer completes the payment, in the final step they are presented with two buttons - Download Invoice and Download Receipt, but there is no button/link for going back to my store. So it's a dead end. Customer can only close their browser tab.

Is there a way to specify something like `success_url` or `home_url` that would add a button for getting the customer back to my store?

Right now as a workaround I'm forcing `hosted_invoice_url` to open in a new tab. Customer closes the tab after they are finished and they get back to my store in the original tab.

Answer (score 2):

From what I know, this is not possible with hosted invoices pages. I'd recommend relaying this use case/feedback directly to [Stripe](https://support.stripe.com/contact).

However, if you were to use [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout) you can pass [`success_url`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-success_url) and [`cancel_url`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-cancel_url) parameters which will fulfil your requirements in this case. Perhaps Checkout might be a better product for your use case?