# Stripe payment redirection issue

Tags: javascript, c#, html, angular, stripe-payments

We have payment button in our website and we are using stripe invoice creation method for the stripe payment and it should be mandatory go with stripe invoice method. When users are clicking the payment button, we are creating the stripe invoice URL and users are redirecting  to  that invoice URL for the payment. But as of now we don't have option to set success URL in the stripe. So how can we close the or how can we redirect the users back to our website after user redirected to stripe invoice URL.  Any alternate solution to solve the redirection issue after completed the payment?
Currently when the user done the payment, user are still in the stripe invoice page.

Thanks in Advance
Roshil

Comment: Are you using Stripe's own Stripe-hosted pages? If so, then does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67719904/can-i-redirect-customer-back-to-my-store-from-stripe-hosted-invoice-page - or if you're using Stripe Checkout then look for the `success_url` and `cancel_url` parameters.

Comment: I am not using stripe checkOut. Its mandatory for us to use stripe checkout. I am using Stripe Invoice creation API.

Comment: Stripe Invoicing is not meant for synchronous online payment. If you wish to have invoicing with redirection, Stripe Checkout Session with Invoicing option that `success_url` and `cancel_url` can be set for redirection: https://stripe.com/docs/receipts?payment-ui=checkout#paid-invoices